# Microsoft Hive ODBC driver 2.1.5 timeout

Tags: hive, odbc, connection-timeout

I recently upgrade to the Microsoft hive odbc driver version 2.01.05.1006, released 12/8/2016.  My code was working with the previous version (1.0) of the driver.  Now when running my code I keep getting the following error.

ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Hardy] (72) Query execution timeout expired.

I have tried changing the timeout settings for the ODBC driver, but it still times out.  Does anybody have any other suggestions?

Comment: Did u ever succeed resolving this issue?