# ERROR [HYT00] [Microsoft] [Hardy] Query execution timeout expired. Hive ODBC connection

Tags: c#, hadoop, hive, odbc

Using Microsoft Hive ODBC Driver hive 2.1.12.1017 to connect with Hive on linux machine which have hadoop setup.
Select query with large data give this error:
**ERROR [HYT00] [Microsoft] [Hardy] Query execution timeout expired.**

Image of exact error is in the link.
[http://prntscr.com/j2sux6][1]

Strange thing is sometimes query does not give any error sometime it does with same parameters.

Any kind of help will really be appreciated.

[Microsoft Hive ODBC driver 2.1.5 timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41148927/microsoft-hive-odbc-driver-2-1-5-timeout) found this relative but there is not answer unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I'm too facing the issue for ODBC I change the command timeout time but I don't think that it will be a good thing because increasing that too give some error sometime. More over I'm facing the issue in `insert`, `select` is working fine. `update` and `delete` not checked.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30305962)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am also facing timeout while retrieving data through Hive ODBC driver using powershell. I've tried extending the ConnectionTimeout and CommandTimeout times.

```
function Get-ODBC-Data {
  param(
    [string]$query=$(throw 'query is required.'),
    [string]$dsn
  )
  $conn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
  $conn.ConnectionString = "DSN=$dsn;"
  $conn.ConnectionTimeout = 3600                  # Here setup ConnectionTimeout
  $conn.open()

  $cmd = New-object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($query,$conn)
  $cmd.CommandTimeout = 3600                      # Here setup CommandTimeout
  $ds = New-Object system.Data.DataSet
  (New-Object system.Data.odbc.odbcDataAdapter($cmd)).fill($ds) #| out-null
  $conn.close()
  return $ds.Tables
}
$dsn = "Hive"

$query = "SHOW DATABASES;"
Get-ODBC-Data -query $query -dsn $dsn
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34946413)